# General OO design pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, delegates, notifications

Consider the following general program structure:

- Class A has an instance of Class B as a member variable
- Class B has a collection member variable containing instances of class C
- Events in class A are propagated to the C instances by A simply telling B about the event

**What are the design patterns concerning instances of class C talking back to class A?**

One option is instances of class C posting notifications to which class A subscribes. Another option is passing a reference to class A "down the chain" (from A to B then from B to each C). This latter option allows instances of C to talk directly to A.

Comment: [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit for design & conceptual questions.

Comment: Are you looking for design paterns specifically or for the optimum solution which may use a design pattern?

Comment: Design patterns exist to solve problems that occur with some frequency in a given context. You didn't specify any problem that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean *design patterns* literally (i.e. of the GoF variety) then these would be a few relevant options:

- Command: pass a callback to the `C` items (directly or indirectly through B) so that when they want to talk back to `A` they can simply invoke this callback -- which can even have parameters
- Iterator: `B` exposes a view of its aggregate collection directly to `A`; communication between `A` and `C` is then made directly
- Mediator: Exposes notifications to which `A` and `C` might subscribe to; communication is done by posting events
- Observer: What you already suggested as the first option

If on the other hand you really mean *architectural* patterns, then typical options are:

- Your first option, `A` subscribing to `C` events. At first sight this doesn't look like an all-around good idea unless the event is extremely useful all the time, because it requires `n` objects to aggregate a pointer back to the callback which in the worst case they could even use just once.
- Passing references to `A` is another option, but not a good one if you are going to pollute the public interface of `A` with methods just so that `C` can call back to it in very specific scenarios. It can be very effective if `A` already exposes a suitable interface, but be aware that you might need an adapter class between `C` calling back to `A` in order to not tightly couple `C` to `A`'s interface.
- A third option would be `A` iterating over (a view of) the collection provided by `B` directly and supplying callbacks to `C` instances; this has the advantages of being quite loosely coupled and that it will use the least amount of memory, but it might be a bit trickier to code.